# Talend custom component dependency issue

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, talend

I am creating the components for the Talend similar to Jira and Azure.

I got success in creating and installing the component into the TOS(Talend Studio), able edit the configuration of the installed components.
But while trying to run the job, Talend asks for the dependency which is jar generated during the POM packaging

> **org.talend.components.trial-0.16.0.jar**

I am using the bundle file

> **org.talend.components.trial-0.16.0-bundle.jar**

to install the components.

If I provide the

> **org.talend.components.trial-0.16.0.jar**

file, then job runs successfully, and if I don't provide the dependency then, TOS job gives the error

> org.talend not found

Is there any solution by which I don't need to install the Jar file. because all classes of the jar is already supplied in the bundle jar.

Answer (score 0):

Talend must be having a classpath mentioned somewhere. Most of the time it's in a batch file or manifest file of its main jar file. The name of the file under classpath is not having *bundle.jar in it and hence the problem.

Solution would be,

- Change the classpath attribute to have a name of file containing *bundle.jar.

  Or
- If you have a control of creating this *bundle.jar file, you can rename it to remove *bundle* in it. 
  Ex- If this bundle.jar file is generated as apart of maven project, you can add ***finalName*** tag in pom.xml to rename the jar file.

Comment: Yes,its maven project generates 2 files one *.bundle.jar and other is *.jar. i am using the bundle jar which contains all the classes same as *.jar.

Comment: I extracted both jars having same classes,only difference is the bundle file contains other jar dependencies

Comment: Ok. Then you need include name of bundle.jar in your talend classpath.

Comment: Tried to add final in name, also tried to generate the component using command given at Talend repo, no luck same issue occur

Comment: Can you share the script line that invokes talend ? I want to see what are you providing in the classpath attributes.

Comment: return new SimpleRuntimeInfo(this.getClass().getClassLoader(),
     DependenciesReader.computeDependenciesFilePath(MAVEN_GROUP_ID, MAVEN_ARTIFACT_ID),
     trialCompSource.class.getCanonicalName());

Comment: No. I mean the launch script. Example a shell script that has java -jar command written. Intention is to check -classpath attribute that has file names that will be made available on classpath.

Comment: I am not running any shell script, just installing the generated jar into the Talend itself.

Comment: I tried to check classpath for  missing classes and also added manually but no luck